# How to remove dark lines formed when texture painting?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

[image: texture painting in blender]
For some reason there are dark thick lines around shoulders, chest and hips. When I try to paint them they just become very dark version of the color. How can I remove them?

Comment: flipped normals maybe, try to recalculate them CTRL+N in edit mode

Comment: Also can you confirm that painting in the 2d editor still shows dark or if they show up correctly?

Comment: That could be mipmapping as well (another guess though). Check if these black lines appear around seams on your mesh. If they do then try painting with a bit increased Bleed option in the Toolshelf > Options (2-5 px). Certain areas possible to paint manually in UV editor as well